# $e^{-x}\cdot f(x)=2+\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+t^4}dt$ , for all $x \in (-1,1)$. Find $(f^{-1})^{'}(2)?$

Tags: definite-integrals, inverse-function

I have tried to find the $\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+t^4}$ but it appears its answer is $\Gamma^2(\frac{1}{4})\cdot \frac{1}{8\cdot\sqrt{\pi}}$. But can anyone tell me how to solve this problem. Here  f be a real valued function defined on the interval (−1, 1).

Comment: If $f(x) = C e^{x}$, $f^{-1}(x)=\log\left(\frac{x}{C}\right)$ and the value of $C$ **does not** affect the value of $(f^{-1})'(2).$

Comment: The RHS is a constant wrt $x$, i.e. $f(x)=ce^x$.

Comment: Ina an earlier question today I asked the integration $\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+t^4}$ and got the answer as this.

Comment: @Saradamani: computing/approximating $\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+t^4}\,dt$ can be nice but it is completely irrelevant for the task at hand.

Comment: Jack D'Aurizo Sir can you please elaborate? I am really struggling with this problem for hours an end.

Comment: @Saradamani: $$ \frac{d}{dx}\log\left(\frac{x}{C}\right) = \frac{1}{x}$$ no matter what $C$ is.

Comment: @Saradamani: you are focussing on the integral, but it is just a number (and you can add 2 to it and get another number - call it C).  The point is you can leave it as C and never calculate it: it does not affect the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $C = 2+\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+t^4}dt$:

$$e^{-x}\cdot f(x)= C$$
$$f(x)= Ce^x$$
$$f^{-1}(x) = \ln\left(\frac{x}{C}\right)$$
$$[f^{-1}(x)]' = \frac{1}{x}$$
$$\therefore [f^{-1}(2)]' = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Thats it! Is it that easy. oh how!

Comment: @Saradamani Jack commented this twice...

Comment: Oh sorry thanks @Jack,@Andrew.